# How do I set cookie values dynamically in "HTTP CookiesManager" i.e. ai_user & ai_session for incoming user in ecommerce site in JMeter?

Tags: cookies, jmeter, session-cookies, cookie-session, usersession

I want to set user defined cookies value i.e. **ai_user & ai_session** dynamically for each user in "HTTP CookiesManager" in JMeter, as it happens in browser ecommerce website. It's hard code for now but I want it's value dynamic & unique for each incoming user.

Answer (score 0):

It's sufficient to add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan and it will **automatically** handle incoming cookies

If it doesn't - most probably something is wrong with the application you're testing, i.e. it responds with invalid or expired cookies. If this is the case you can consider changing the "Implementation" to something less-restrictive

[image]

and/or add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)

Also it's always possible to handle the cookies manually by extracting them from [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and add them to resulting JMeter Variables to HTTP Cookie Manager (or [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager))